# apache FTPClient deleting file on FTP while it is uploading

Tags: java, apache, ftp

The FTPClient (org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient) hangs up when another Client consume (delete/move) the file while the FTP is still uploading.
Here is the code how i upload the file:

```
    ftpClient = getFTPConnection();
    BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    OutputStream os = ftpClient.storeFileStream(filename);
    int readCount = 0;
    while ((readCount = buffIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }

    os.close();
    buffIn.close();
    inputStream.close();

    ftpClient.completePendingCommand(); //!stuck here!
    ftpClient.rename(filename, "uploadRename.txt");
    ftpClient.logout();
    ftpClient.disconnect();
```

When the file is deleted while uploading, the  os.write finish its work (that is ok.) but after when calling completePendingCommand() the program stay stuck. 
The ftpClient.completePendingCommand() have to be done to make a second command if i understood this right, removing it is not the solution.
Anyone any idea why the ftpClient hangs?
I just expect an error message or a timeout if completePendingCommand does not get what he want from the ftp.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your situation, but when I try to modify a file during its upload, server reply with a 450 code and does not allow file deletion.

By the way, as Commons-net API doc is little curt, you can try to invoke the `ftp.getReplyCode()` method to find out what is exactly happening, before the `completePendingCommand()` call.

Then, you can match the reply code in [this table](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/constant-values.html) and decide what to do "switching" the reply code.